# Changing the redirectUri of authenticated referral

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0, referrals

I'm wondering if there is a way to change the action of clicking "cancel" on the Authenticated Referral auth. The url for the auth shows the redirectUri parameter, but there seems to be no way of changing it. It would be nice to use authenticated referrals, but still allow users to test-drive the app.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I don’t think there is – it’s core FB functionality.

Your only option IMHO would be *not* to use authenticated referrals, and prompt the user for permissions once they arive on your canvas/page tab, using FB.login there – if they abort that, you can react accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've had to do. The "Go To App" button is so much more friendly though! :o)